# What does the Deep Dungeons of Doom floppy contain?

Tags: surgeon-simulator-2013

In the reception area, there is a red floppy disk. I can't quite seem to be able to get it into the computer,  but is it even worth it? What is on that disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All it contains is some pre-rendered "gameplay" of what appears to be an RPG. You can't interact with it in any way other than to watch it repeat itself fairly quickly.

I managed to get the disk in the drive, so I can actually show you exactly what it has on it!

[image]

Comment: That is kind of a bummer; I figured it'd be something cool. How/Where did you get those other floppy disks?

Comment: They just started showing up after I'd complete surgeries. I guess they're kind of like progress markers?

Comment: This is a real game, by the way.  And it's pretty cool.  You guys should play it.  http://www.deepdungeonsofdoom.com/

Comment: And it's made by same developer,that's why it is in the game as easter egg.